# Messages not going into Queue

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq

I've got RabbitMQ 3.5.7 with Erlang 20.1 setup and running. I've also got PostgreSQL 9.5 running on the same server.

In Rabbit I've got the plugin `pgsql-listen-exchange` installed from here:

https://github.com/gmr/pgsql-listen-exchange

According to `rabbitmq-plugins list` it is there and running:

```
[E*] pgsql_listen_exchange             0.3.0-v3.5.x
```

I've created an exchange and channel inside Rabbit Management UI to send messages from PGSQL to:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I login to PGSQL from the CLI and try to send a `NOTIFY` message it never comes through:

[image]

What am I missing, I've followed the directions on the GIT page and docs for Rabbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [github reference](https://github.com/gmr/pgsql-listen-exchange) you provided,

the exchange behaves like a [direct exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html), which means you need to provide the proper bindings between the exchange "MyChannel" and the queue "MyChannel" *(would recommend you change the names of those before going to production, btw)*.

You have defined one binding with an empty routing key.

In your test (again based on the github information):

```
NOTIFY MyChannel, 'This is a test'
```

Would create a message with a routing key "MyChannel".
As the binding you configured (empty string) doesn't match the routing key provided "MyChannel", the message is not transmitted to the queue.